# Infinite fraction series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, continued-fractions

The infinite fraction $$f(n)=n+\frac{n}{n+\frac{n}{n+...}}$$ can be simplified to $$f(n)=\frac{n+\sqrt{n^2-4n}}{2}$$ However, I wanted to know if the fraction $$1+\frac{2}{3+\frac{4}{5+...}}$$ can be simplified further to get an answer using algebra or is the answer a transcendental number? On solving this in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)(till 25), I got 1.54149408254.
[This is an image of the Desmos page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehku4.png)

Comment: AFAIK, this can't be solved using algebra. It is transcendental, I am 99.99% sure.

Comment: @LeonhardEuler _You_ solved it, about 250 years ago! See my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes, I didn't tell because I wanted to see whether today's mathematicians can solve it or not :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Mathworld page on continued fraction constants](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html) gives the exact answer as
$$\frac1{\sqrt e-1}$$
which is indeed transcendental.

The value was known to Euler himself. See page 14 of [this translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508227).

Comment: But what does 'K' mean as a notation in the Mathworld page and how did they derive the answer?

Comment: @AyaanMaan I think they just referred to Euler's paper and the OEIS sequence attached to that continued fraction. The K is just another odd notation for continued fractions.